# ERROR: class not abstract and does not override abstract method

Tags: java

I'm having difficulties on debugging this code. I've tried a lot of alternatives to get rid of the error but I can't seem to point out what's wrong since I'm new to Java.

```
public abstract class Animal {

    private String name;    
    private String type;

    public Animal(String name, String type) {       
       this.name = name;
       this.type = type;    
    }       

   public String getName() {        
        return this.name;
   }

   public String getType() {        
       return this.type;    
   }        

   public abstract void speak();

 }



public class Dog extends Animal{


    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();     }

    public String getType() {       
       return super.getType();  }

    public void speak(String name, String type){
        System.out.println("arf!");     }

    }


public class Ark{
    static void main(String[] args){

        Dog cookie = new Dog();         
        cookie.speak();

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please post your error ?

Comment: Seriously, don't indent your code like that! Put the closing brackets on the next lines!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract void speak();
```

You need to implement this in  `Dog`

What you have implemented

```
public void speak(String name, String type)
{ System.out.println("arf!"); }
```

Hence `Dog` is abstract but you haven't specified that, niether you implemented `speak()` **without parameters**. Remove the parameters, anyways you are not using them.

```
@Override
public void speak()
{ System.out.println("arf!"); }
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much for the response! removed the parameters and the error message now is "constructor Animal in class Animal cannot be applied to given types;

public class Dog extends Animal{"

Comment: Animal class has parameterized constructor, so when Dog class extends it compiler inserts super() (without arguments) which invokes the default constructor of the superclass (Animal) which you don't have, hence the error

Comment: One solution is to create parameterized constructor for Dog.
**
public Dog(String name, String type) {
   super(name, type);
}**

Answer (score 0):

The Abstract Speak Method doesn't have the same arguments that your implemented Dog.speak(String String) has.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override speak method in Dog class, change it to

```
public void speak()
{ 
   System.out.println("arf!"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class Animal {

    private String name;    
   private String type;

    public Animal(String name, String type) {       
       this.name = name;
        this.type = type;   }       

   public String getName() {        
        return
        this.name;  }

    public String getType() {       
         return this.type;  }       

   public abstract void speak(String name, String type);    
 // if you want parameters in the Dog class for this method you must include them here otherwise it wont work
}



 public class Dog extends Animal{


    public String getName() {
        return super.getName();     }

    public String getType() {       
       return super.getType();  }

    public void speak(String name, String type){
        System.out.println("arf!");     }

 }
```